# creating XY Chart between different points with jfreechart

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart

I am trying to create a interconnect between multiple points in a XY chart with jfreechart. This `chart.add( 1.0 , 4.0 );chart.add( 2.0 , 5.0 ); chart.add( 2.5 , 7.0 );` sort of connects them in a line. Like this - [wrong image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve66E.png). But I want to return back to the 1st point and create a chart like this -[correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5RCT.png). And I want to repeat it for multiple base nodes. Something like this -

```
for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<=30;j++){
    chart.add(arr1[i], arr2[j]);
  }
}
```

How can I go about this ?

Comment: I tried this. But it results in the same wrong plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Try using multiple XYSeries:

In the XYSeries constructor set autosort to false to allow the lines to go backwards if needed, and set allowDuplicates to true if you may need to navigate a series through a point that has already been plotted.

```
    final XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Data 1", false, true);
    series1.add( 1.0 , 4.0 );
    series1.add( 2.0 , 5.0 );

    final XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Data 2", false, true);
    series2.add( 1.0 , 4.0 );
    series2.add( 2.5 , 7.0 );

    final XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection();
    data.addSeries(series1);
    data.addSeries(series2);

    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "XY Chart",
            "X",
            "Y",
            data,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false
    );
```

To add further data series, use more invocations of XYSeriesCollection.addSeries(series).